# Can't display SVG images

Tags: html, django, svg, assets

I can't manage to display and SVG image in an HTML template.

I'm working with Django, and this is how my HTML looks like:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="{% static 'user_template_2/assets/test.svg' %}"></use></svg>
```

The path and the filename are correct (I get a `200` response in the browser when requesting them), I'm loading other static assets using that same directory.

I've already added this to my settings file:

```py
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svg", True)
mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svgz", True)
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: are you getting a 404 when pinging the image url?

Comment: @Sumithran no, I get a 200

Comment: I don't use django all that much so I'm not sure what is legal, but can you use the svg as and `<img>` tag rather than an `<svg>` tag?

Comment: @need_to_know_now yeah that should work, but you will lose the interactivity.

Comment: @Sumithran How would that translate to loss of interactivity? I'm not very familiar with Django so please fill me in

Comment: @need_to_know_now [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image)

Comment: @Sumithran Right, that's fair, but maybe OP can assess his requirement for the image(whether he wants it to be interactive or not) and decide to use the svg as an HTML or not. Personally, i haven't had too much trouble using SVG's in `<img>` tags in React.

Answer (score 2):

1. `<use>` elements should point to an **SVG element**.  Not a whole SVG file.

   > **xlink:href = ""**
   > A IRI reference to an element/fragment within an SVG document.

   In other words:

   ```
   xlink:href="{% static 'user_template_2/assets/test.svg#some-element-id' %}"
   ```
2. Your `<svg>` element may need a `width` and `height`.  And possibly also a `viewBox`.  Unless you are already setting it explicitly, or implicitly in your CSS.  There's a possibility that the SVG contents may be outside the bounds of the SVG viewport area, and thus not visible.